# Странное поведение конструкции if-else в AJAX запросе с CSS

Tags: php, css, ajax, проверка

Здравствуйте! Помогите, пожалуйста, понять один момент. Есть форма регистрации. Сделал для себя максимальную проверку логина на JS и PHP. Теперь хочу сделать проверку логина на уникальность на Jquery, используя AJAX запросы. Весь код прекрасно работает с AJAX запросами, используя GET или POST методы. Но используя тот или другой просыпаются косяки с изменением CSS того или иного элемента в зависимости от условия. Причем разницы нет, какой метод ты используешь, т.е. скорость работы скрипта остается и так, и так медленной, если использовать AJAX. А медленность ее проявляется в том, например:

Если набрать в форму логин, имеющийся в БД, скрипт быстренько проверяет и выводит соответствующее сообщение, что пользователь с таким логином уже имеется и выделяет все красным. Теперь вводим другой логин, допустим, на 2 символ короче (чтобы скрипт ушел в правило длины символов). После отщелкивания от input'a (произошло событие blur), т.е. скрипт должен выполниться сначала, начинаются тормоза. Продолжает висеть сообщение, что такой пользователь зарегистрирован, и новый текст в div не подгружается. Потом пройдет секунд 10 и только тогда он подгрузится и покажет, что надо. Иногда такого не бывает, как я описал, иногда бывает :) В поисках заветной закономерности сижу. Проблему с зависанием CSS стиля можно словить если туда-сюда выходить на правильные-неправильные условия.

Поиграться с примером можно [здесь](http://test.tstagan.ru/registration.php) (на тестовой версии моего сайта). Логин *troyx* уже имеется в БД. Если специально попадать под разный условия, то CSS стиль не сейчас, так скоро на форме все-таки подвиснет, а хотя не должен, так как работает по строгим правилам.

Помогите разобраться. Уже 3 дня голову ломаю.

### HTML-код

```
<div class="input_item" >
Логин: <span class="redstar">*</span>
<div><input type="text" class="empty_field" name="login" id="login" maxlength="16" placeholder="Например: svetlov" value="<?php echo $login; ?>"/>
<img src="images/check.png" class="inputImgLogin" /><img src="images/loading.gif" class="inputImgLoadingLogin" /></div>
<div id="valid_login" class="empty_field_text" ></div>
</div>
```

### JS код

```
        $('#login').blur(function() {
            $("#login").css({'border-color':''});
            $('#valid_login').text('');
            $('.inputImgLogin').css({'display' : 'none'});
            if($(this).val() != '') {
                var pattern = /^[0-9a-z-_]+/i;
                if(pattern.test($(this).val())){
                    if($(this).val().length > 3) {
                        $('.inputImgLoadingLogin').css({'display' : 'inline-block'});
                        login =  $("#login").val();
                        $.ajax({
                            url:  "test.php",
                            type:  "GET",
                            data:  "login=" + login,
                            cache:  false,
                            success:  function(response){
                                if(response  == "no"){
                                    $('.inputImgLoadingLogin').css({'display' : 'none'});
                                    $("#login").css({'border-color':'#d8512d'});
                                    $('.inputImgLogin').css({'display' : 'none'});
                                    $('#valid_login').text('Пользователь с таким логином уже существует');
                                    $("#login").addClass('empty_field');
                                } else{
                                    $('.inputImgLoadingLogin').css({'display' : 'none'});
                                    $("#login").css({'border-color' : '#008040'});
                                    $('.inputImgLogin').css({'display' : 'inline-block'});
                                    $('#valid_login').text('');
                                    $('#valid_login').removeClass('empty_field_text');
                                    $("#login").removeClass('empty_field');
                                }                                             
                            }
                        });
                    } else {                
                        $(this).css({'border-color':'#d8512d'});
                        $('.inputImgLogin').css({'display' : 'none'});
                        $('#valid_login').text('Слишком короткий логин');
                        $(this).addClass('empty_field');
                    }
                } else {
                    $(this).css({'border-color':'#d8512d'});
                    $('.inputImgLogin').css({'display' : 'none'});
                    $('#valid_login').text('Некорректный логин');
                    $(this).addClass('empty_field');
                }
            } else {
                $(this).css({'border-color':'#d8512d'});
                $('.inputImgLogin').css({'display' : 'none'});
                $('#valid_login').text('Поле не должно быть пустым');
                $(this).addClass('empty_field');
            }
        });
```

### PHP-код

```
include ("scripts/db_connect.php");
$login = $_GET['login'];
$login_select_query = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '$login'", $connect);
$login_select_list = mysql_fetch_array($login_select_query);
if (empty($login_select_list['id'])) {
    echo "yes";
} else {
    echo "no";
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас при событии blur отсылается порядка 1000 AJAX запросов[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А зачем вы проверяете поля через setInterval()? Замените этот код

```js
setInterval(function() {
  // Запускаем функцию проверки полей на заполненность
  checkInput();
  // Считаем к-во незаполненных полей
  var sizeEmpty = form.find('.empty_field').size();
  // Вешаем условие-тригер на кнопку отправки формы
  if (sizeEmpty > 0) {
    if (btn.hasClass('disabled')) {
      return false
    } else {
      btn.addClass('disabled')
    }
  } else {
    btn.removeClass('disabled')
  }
}, 500);
```

в крайнем случае на такой

```js
form.find('.rfield').keyUp(function() {
  // Запускаем функцию проверки полей на заполненность
  checkInput();
  // Считаем к-во незаполненных полей
  var sizeEmpty = form.find('.empty_field').size();
  // Вешаем условие-тригер на кнопку отправки формы
  if (sizeEmpty > 0) {
    if (btn.hasClass('disabled')) {
      return false
    } else {
      btn.addClass('disabled')
    }
  } else {
    btn.removeClass('disabled')
  }
});
```

В этом случае форма будет проверяться не каждых .5 секунды (500 миллисекунд), а при вводе текста в каждое поле. И лучше не слать на проверку уже проверенные поля либо поля, которые пользователь еще не успел заполнить. Пример могу завтра показать, сегодня уже бошка не варит :)

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Заново переписал грамотно код. Избавился от вызова CSS в коде, перенес все на классы. Все отлично работает, без сбоев. Еще раз спасибо за наводку ;)

Comment: пожалста, был рад помочь :)